# Append files having different variables

Tags: python

I have 3 files in the following format-

File1:

```
ID Var1 Var2
001 5 10
002 12 6
```

File2:

```
ID Var1 Var3 Var5
003 5 10 9
004 12 6 1
```

File3:

```
ID Var3 Var4
005 5 10
006 12 6
```

and I want the output in following format

```
ID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
001 5 10 0 0 0
002 12 6 0 0 0
003 5 0 10 0 9
004 12 0 6 0 1
005 0 0 5 10 0
006 0 0 12 6 0
```

Please let me know how I can do that in python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Are these spaces between the values in your files, or tabs? Have you looked at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)? It can do this more or less out-of-the-box.

Comment: @ TimPietzcker - these are the spaces in the file       @MartijnPieters - i am new to python so any help in getting useful function for doing this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @abhishekraghuvanshi: if you're new, I would simply start with going through [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you should take a look at the csv module, here is something to get you started.

```
outfile = open("output.txt", 'w')
for file_ in os.listdir("\path\to\my\files"):
    with open(file_) as f:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file_):
            if line_number > 0: #omit the headers
                outfile.write(line)
```

Also manipulating files with python seems to be a [fairly common question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+file), perhaps you could search though some of them to see how other people do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#use fileinput module if you're reading multiple files at once
import fileinput
dic = {}         # initialize an empty dict. This swill be used to store the value of
                 # (id,var) pair fetched from the file.

for line in fileinput.input(['file1','file2','file3']):

    #if 'ID' is present in the line then it means it is the header line
    if 'ID' in line:
        vars = line.split()[1:] # extract the vars from it
                                # for file1 vars would be ['Var1', 'Var2']

    else:                            #else it is normal line
         spl =line.split()           # split the line at whitespaces
                                     # for the line '001 5 10\n' this would return
                                     # ['001', '5', '10'] 

        idx, vals = spl[0], spl[1:]  # assign the first value from spl 
                                     # to idx and rest to vals

        #now use zip to iterate over vars and vals, zip will return
        #item on the same index from the iterables passed to it.
        for x, y in zip(vars, vals): 
            dic[idx,x] = y          # use a tuple ('001','Var1') as key and 
                                    # assign the value '5' to it. Similarly
                                    # ('001','Var2') will be assigned '10'

#get a sorted list of unique vars and Ids
vars = sorted(set(item[1] for item in dic))
idxs = sorted(set(item[0] for item in dic), key = int)

print " ".join(vars)  #print header
# now iterate over the IDs and for each ID print the pick var from Vars and print the     
# value of  (id,Var),,, etc.
for x in idxs:
                     # dict.get will return the default value '0' if a 
                     # combination of (id,var) is not found in dict.
    print x," ".join(dic.get((x,y),'0') for y in vars)

    #use string formatting for better looking output.
```

**output:**

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
001 5 10 0 0 0
002 12 6 0 0 0
003 5 0 10 0 9
004 12 0 6 0 1
005 0 0 5 10 0
006 0 0 12 6 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For merging the several files, you could use a function like this, making use of Python's `defaultdict`:

```
def read_from_file(filename, dictionary):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        head, body = lines[0].split(), lines[1:]
        for line in body:
            for i, item in enumerate(line.split()):
                if i == 0:
                    d = dictionary[item]
                else:
                    d[head[i]] = item

from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
d = defaultdict(defaultdict)
read_from_file("file1", d)
read_from_file("file2", d)
read_from_file("file3", d)
pprint(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'001': defaultdict(None, {'Var1': '5', 'Var2': '10'}),
 '002': defaultdict(None, {'Var1': '12', 'Var2': '6'}),
 '003': defaultdict(None, {'Var5': '9', 'Var1': '5', 'Var3': '10'}),
 '004': defaultdict(None, {'Var5': '1', 'Var1': '12', 'Var3': '6'}),
 '005': defaultdict(None, {'Var4': '10', 'Var3': '5'}),
 '006': defaultdict(None, {'Var4': '6', 'Var3': '12'})}
```

Now all that's left to do is to pretty-print this dictionary of dictionaries as a table.